# Não consigo colocar a tela de login fora do ui-view que esta no index.html, estou usando angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Codigo  do app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','ui.select','ui.date','dialogs.main', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
        $stateProvider

            .state('login', {
                url:'/login',
                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/login/login.html",
                controller: "loginCtrl",
                data: {
                    requireLogin: false
                  }
            })
            .state('apresentacao', {

                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/aih/principal/apresentacao.html",
                controller: "ApresentacaoCtrl"
            })
            .state("apresentacao.guiaIdentificacaoPaciente", {

                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/aih/guias/IdentificacaoPaciente/GuiaIdentificacaoPaciente.html",
                controller: "PacienteCtrl"
            })

            .state("apresentacao.guiaIdentificacaoInternacao", {
                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/aih/guias/IdentificacaoInternacao/GuiaIdentificacaoInternacao.html",
                controller: "identificacaoInternacaoCtrl"
            })

            .state("apresentacao.guiaDiagnosticos", {
                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/aih/guias/Diagnosticos/GuiaDiagnosticos.html",
                controller: "diagnosticosCtrl"
            })

            .state("apresentacao.guiaProcedimentosRealizados", {
                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/aih/guias/ProcedimentosRealizados/GuiaProcedimentosRealizados.html",
                controller: "procedimentosRealizadosCtrl"
            })

            .state('hospital', {

                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/gerenciar-hospital/gerenciar-hospital.html",
                controller: "GerenciarHospitalCtrl"
            })

            .state('terceiros', {

                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/gerenciar-terceiros/gerenciar-terceiros.html",
                controller: "GerenciarTerceirosCtrl"
            })
            .state('profissionais', {

                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/gerenciar-profissionais/gerenciar-profissionais.html",
                controller: "GerenciarProfissionaisCtrl"
            })
            .state('operadores', {

                templateUrl: "vita/view/faturamento/gerenciar-operadores/gerenciar-operadores.html",
                controller: "GerenciarOperadoresCtrl"
            });



    });
```

}());